# visual studio crash when try to start kernel debugger

Tags: crash, kernel, visual-studio-2015, driver, wdk

I have a project on my studies to write kernel driver. First step of this project is to prepere working environment, so I installed WDK, installed and configured Windows 7 x64 on virtualbox machine and created hello world kernel driver solution from the internet. After that I could deploy and debug my driver in windows 7 client machine directly from visual studio. Everything worked fine. After few days there was an update to windows 10 (host) - november update 1511, I installed that and (sic!) removed ,,previous Windows installations" to get disk space. Unfortunatelly when I opened my project again - I couldn't deploy and debug my driver due to visual studio crash. I can't find workaround for 3 days which is really frustrating beacause I have to show it to my professor on monday.

What I have tried to do:
I completly reinstalled visual studio and WDK (in host and client machine) and it still happens.
After compile, when I click ,,Debugging tools for Windows - Kernel Debugger", visual studio is crashing
([screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFDyr.jpg))

I can't get previous installation back and now I have no time to reinstall entire system.
Can you help me, please? Is there a way to get it working again?

PS. Excuse me for my english

Comment: Same problem here, but I have already the newest WDK 10.0.10586.0 installed, so the solution doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that.

After I upgraded my OS, I had still installed WDK 10.0.10240, it was not updated to the newer version. Even if I reinstalled it with new wdksetup.exe downloaded from microsoft site, there was still this version. Microsoft did not update their download page. I searched in google "WDK 10.0.10586.11" and I found the direct link to the newest WDK 10.0.10586.0 on tweettunnel.com/vanhoivo.

The link is:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/E/1/CE19C726-6036-4443-845B-A652B0F48CD7/wdk/wdksetup.exe

After I installed this wdk version, the problem has solved, VisualStudio is not crashing now and I can deploy and debug my driver. However, I think that is a bug in VisualStudio - it should show an error that WDK version is not appropriate

Thanks